# Woocommerce match cart items with order items

Tags: woocommerce

I am using woocommerce's session variables to store extra meta data using cart items ID's.  However I now need to access the data when the order is processed and the cart object is destroyed.  Is there a way to match the Cart items with the newly generated order items?

Comment: Have you come up with a solution for this ?